# Render gray-scale pixels based on an array of values between 0 and 1

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to render pixels from an array.

I have an array of data that looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/cURtyptm) (except much larger). From this array I would like to somehow render it so that each number in the array corresponds to a pixel with a shade of gray based on the number value. (0.0 would be white, and 1.0 would be black)

[image: example image of what I would like]

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score -1):

For the array you have given; If you know the width and height of the image you want rendered you can do this:

```
int indx = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        glColor3d(data[indx],data[indx],data[indx]);
        //drawing of it goes here; assuming glVertex2d(x,y);
        indx++;
    }
}
```

For this to work it should be known that width*height < data.length. Increment index for each pixel drawn to go to the next number in the array and draw it accordingly.

Modify the x and y so it draws where you want. Say if locX = locY = 10 then depending on the viewport you should have already set up, then the image will start rendering 10px away from (probably) either the top left or bottom left corner. This part is simple maths if you have already started to learn how to draw in OpenGl and/or LWJGL.

```
int locX, locY;
int indx = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        glColor3d(data[indx],data[indx],data[indx]);
        glVertex2d(locX + x, locY + y);
        indx++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh and this assumes that it is a single dimension array but it easy to adapt for a multi-dimensional one

Comment: It's a 2D array of data, but I can store the colors in a 1d list, So how should I render the image from the color data?

Comment: Drawing each pixel individually will have a terrible performance. Why not upload the data to a single-channel texture and draw one textured quad with linear filtering?